# Why it's assumed long without suffix

Tags: java, types, suffix

The following code does not compile because the value of `x` is a `long` value. So in the second line, it isn't possible assign a long value to `y`.

```
long x = 10;
int y = 2 * x;
```

My question is:
The first line doesn't have the suffix `L` in the variable of type `long`, shouldn't it be assumed to have type `int`?

Comment: Once it's assigned to a `long`, it's a long.

Comment: [Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of your operation must be an `int`. If you don't do a narrowing conversion o.k.a. cast operation, of any primitive number type in your operation to an int, then that means that the result of your operation will be of the wider range number. By casting you are letting the compiler know that you are sure that your result will be within range of an int and that way it knows that you won't seemingly lose information (you can though even if you don't cast and expect a double for example, but that's a completelly different matter). You can find an excellent explanation about the issues regarding your question [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to cast to an `int` before performing the operation.

```
long x = 10;
int y  = 2 * (int)x;
```